# Intercambiar valores de una matriz en Java

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy trabajando en una matriz en Java y me quede estancado ya que necesito que se forme una pirámide invertida de números y para ello necesito representar con 0 los los lugares donde no irán números.

**ENTRADA**: Numero de filas de la matriz

**SALIDA**: La matriz impresa con una piramide de 1's invertida

** La matriz nunca es cuadrada debido a que el numero de columnas es calculado con la expresión ´col=(f*2)-1´ donde ´f´ es el número de filas

Este es mi código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class matriznc{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner filas = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de filas de la matriz: ");
    int f = filas.nextInt();
    int c = (2*f)-1; //Cantidad de columnas
    int z = 0;
    int matriz[][] = new int[f][c];
    for(int i=0;i<f;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese los valores: ["+i+","+j+"]");
            matriz[i][j]= teclado.nextInt();
        }
    }
    //Rellenar con 0 para formar piramide invertida de numeros
    for (int i=1;i<f;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
                    if (matriz[i][j]==matriz[i][0]){
                        matriz[i][j] = z;
                    }
                    else if(j==(c-1)){
                        matriz[i][j] = z;
                        }
                    }
                }       
     //Imprimir el contenido para verificar
     for (int i=0;i<f;i++) {
     for (int j=0;j<c; j++) {
            System.out.print ("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");
                if(j==(c-1)){
                    System.out.println("\n");
                 }  
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Por el momento he logrado esto:

```
     Si la matriz es por ejemplo de 3x5 obtengo(al rellenar con puros 1):
     [1][1][1][1][1]      
     [0][1][1][1][0]     
     [0][1][1][1][0]

     Y lo que necesito es algo del tipo:

     [1][1][1][1][1]      
     [0][1][1][1][0]
     [0][0][1][0][0]
```

No logro encontrar la relación que me permita obtener esto, espero me puedan orientar.

Comment: Creo que hay inconsistencias en esta explicación, por ejemplo podrías decirme que hay que imprimir si la matriz es de 5*5

Comment: La matriz nunca va a ser cuadrada, debido a que la cantidad de columnas esta definida por la expresión (2*f)-1

Comment: entonces la entrada solamente es el número de filas.

Comment: Si, te entiendo yo me equivoque lo corrijo

Comment: Una pregunta más, por que lees datos del teclado , si al final no importan?

Comment: Es que no siempre van a ser 1's pueden ser otros números del 1 al 9 por ejemplo y eso lo debe ingresar el usuario, y necesito formar la pirámide pero solo se me ocurre haciendo la matriz completa y después eliminando los caracteres que no se usan o no son parte de la piramide. En el ejemplo use 1's por comodidad nada más.

Comment: osea el usuario va a meter numeros random en cualquier parte de la matriz y tu solamente tienes que mostrar los numeros que esten dentro de la piramide, y los demas seran 0's?

Comment: Exacto! ese es el problema en cuestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

📖 Dado que:

> Cuando se crea un arreglo (o *matriz*), cada elemento del arreglo recibe un valor por defecto: `0` o `0.0` para los elementos de tipo primitivo numéricos, `false` para elementos booleanos y `null` para referencias (Deitel 2012, p. 243).

💻 Puesto que la matriz *ya* contiene ceros, entonces sólo hay que limitar la entrada del usuario, usando la condición apropiada:

*Código:*

```java
int matrix[][] = new int[f][c];

for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        if (j >= i && j < c - i) {
            System.out.printf("Ingrese los valores [%d,%d]: ", i, j);
            matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        System.out.printf("[%d]", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Salida:*

```
Ingrese los valores [0,0]: 1
Ingrese los valores [0,1]: 2
Ingrese los valores [0,2]: 3
Ingrese los valores [1,1]: 4
```

```
[1][2][3]
[0][4][0]
```

---

📓 ***Referencias***

Deitel, P. & Deitel, H. (2012). *Java : How to program.* Upper Saddle River, N.J: Prentice Hall.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que me dices, es fácil saber donde esta la piramide y donde no esta gnorando así los espacios donde no esta y poniendo 0's en su lugar.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de filas de la matriz: ");
int f = sc.nextInt();
int c = (2*f)-1; //Cantidad de columnas
int cont = 0;
int matriz[][] = new int[f][c];

for(int i=0;i<f;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
        //si te das cuenta los espacios que hay que ir dejando en 0's va aumentando a la derecha y a la izquierda de 1 en 1, empezando en 0
       for(int k=0; k<cont;k++){
          //ignoramos las entradas y ponemos 0's
           sc.nextInt();
           matriz[i][k]=0;
        }
         for(int k=cont; k<c-cont;k++){
          //Luego los que si importan
           matriz[i][k]=sc.nextInt();
        }
         for(int k=c-cont; k<c;k++){
          //Las que no importan del lado derecho
           sc.nextLine();
           matriz[i][k]=0;
        }

        cont+=1;

    }
  }

 //Imprimir el contenido para verificar
 for (int i=0;i<f;i++) {
 for (int j=0;j<c; j++) {
        System.out.print ("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");
            if(j==(c-1)){
                System.out.println("\n");
             }  
          }
       }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

modifique un poco tu código, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
public static void matriz(){
        Scanner filas = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de filas de la matriz: ");
        int f = filas.nextInt();
        int c = (2*f)-1; //Cantidad de columnas
        int z = 0;
        int matriz[][] = new int[f][c];
        for(int i=0;i<f;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
                System.out.println("Ingrese los valores: ["+i+","+j+"]");
                matriz[i][j]= teclado.nextInt();
            }
        }
        //Rellenar con 0 para formar piramide invertida de numeros
        int cont = 1;
        for (int i=1;i<f;i++){
            int total=0;
                    for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
                        matriz[i][0]=z;
                        total = j;
                    }
                    matriz[i][total]=z;
                    if(i>1){
                        for(int n=0;n<cont;n++){
                            matriz[i][total-n]=z;
                        }
                        for(int s=0;s<cont;s++){
                            matriz[i][s]=z;
                        }
                    }
                    cont=cont+1;
        }
         //Imprimir el contenido para verificar
         for (int i=0;i<f;i++) {
         for (int j=0;j<c; j++) {
                System.out.print ("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");
                    if(j==(c-1)){
                        System.out.println("\n");
                     }  
                  }
               }
    }
```

Cualquier duda estoy al pendiente.

O lo puedes hacer como Paul Vargas